# Getting a very strange error when trying to import requests or beautiful soup

Tags: python, module, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am very new to python and programming in general. I am trying to import both beautiful soup and requests modules. When I try to import either module in a .py file and run it through idle I get a very long and strange error.

Even though I am receiving the same error for each of them, I cannot find anyone else who has experienced the same issue. Any help is very appreciated!

windows 10
python 3.7.0

As far as I can tell I have the paths to python and python scripts set up correctly. I am pretty sure I have the modules installed correctly because when I run pip freeze I get:

```
arcade==1.3.7
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
future==0.17.1
h11==0.8.1
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.8
lxml==4.3.3
Pillow==5.4.1
pyglet==1.3.2
requests==2.21.0
requests3==0.0.0
six==1.12.0
soupsieve==1.9
urllib3==1.24.1
webencodings==0.5.1
xmlx==2.0.0
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling python. I did originally have a few different versions downloaded, so I am wondering if this maybe caused the issue some how. I now have only 3.7.0 installed. I have checked and doubled check that the path is set up correctly. I have tried installing the libraries a bunch of different times and ways.

My file is saved and ran as such:

```
import requests
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 900, in _find_spec
AttributeError: '_SixMetaPathImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/NeckR/Desktop/py/ifthisworks.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\NeckR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\NeckR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\NeckR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\NeckR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 963, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 902, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 879, in _find_spec_legacy
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 449, in spec_from_loader
  File "C:\Users\NeckR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 216, in is_package
    return hasattr(self.__get_module(fullname), "__path__")
  File "C:\Users\NeckR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 118, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
  File "C:\Users\NeckR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Users\NeckR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:/Users/NeckR/Desktop/py\http.py", line 9
    print 'Serving HTTP on port %s ...' % PORT
                                      ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('Serving HTTP on port %s ...' % PORT)?
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to run python2 scripts with python3 interpreter. 
First of all, try to use `print` with parentheses

```
print('Serving HTTP on port %s ...' % PORT)
```

Also, it looks like you have an import problem when some external library tries to do something like `import http` and first module that it finds is your `py/http.py`. Try to rename your module to something more unique.

Also, you have two `requests` library and one of then definitely for python2. How did you install them? Try to uninstall them both and install proper one - for python3.

Comment: Sorry I am a little lost here. I am not trying to print anything. The only code I have saved in the file is import requests

Comment: It's definitely a package problem then: answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by deleting every file associated with python that I could find and then just reinstalling everything. Classic